# How to find the start date, end date and event name from a list and have it update / show based on current time?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of events (with event start, event end and event name) and I want to have a "Current Event Start", "Current Event End" and "Event Name" display based on the current time.

Also I would like to display the "Next Event Start" etc.

However, when the current date and time do not fall into the time frames of one of the events I would like it be blank.

[See here for layout and examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKlVa.png)

So within the image, I've "hard-coded" the dates for the event start (1st grey table), it reads 'a' in Event Name because the "Current Date" falls in Event A's timeframe.

In grey table 2, the current date doesn't fall into a timeframe of any event so the current event is empty but the "Next Event" details are there because if it were the 11/1/22 then the next event is 'b', which starts on 13/1/22.

I have tried some formulae, but am unsure exactly what the syntax would be. I think I have cracked Next Event Start - Cell F16 has the following formula and inputs into G16 and H16:

```
=index(A3:C, IF(MATCH(G14,A3:A,1)=(G14), MATCH(G14,A3:A,1), MATCH(G14,A3:A,1) +1))
```

So my question is how would I make it so "Current Event" details appear when the current date falls into an event timeframe? And when the current time is not in a time frame, for it to be empty?